# Flash drive not showing when inserted and shows allocated space

Tags: partitioning, usb, gparted

I'm trying to fix a flash drive that isn't showing up when I insert it into the USB port.

When I start `GParted` I can see the drive. I can delete it, and create a new one, and everything goes fine but then there is a red exclamation mark next to the name that says that the drive has whole space unallocated.

When I check the drive it doesn't show anything suspicious: (at least that I can see)

```
Check and repair file system (ext4) on /dev/sdc1  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
        
calibrate /dev/sdc1  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
        
path: /dev/sdc1 (partition)
start: 2048
end: 120844287
size: 120842240 (57.62 GiB)
check file system on /dev/sdc1 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
        
e2fsck -f -y -v -C 0 '/dev/sdc1'  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
        
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

11 inodes used (0.01%, out of 195840)
0 non-contiguous files (0.0%)
0 non-contiguous directories (0.0%)
# of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
Extent depth histogram: 3
29830 blocks used (3.81%, out of 781984)
0 bad blocks
1 large file

0 regular files
2 directories
0 character device files
0 block device files
0 fifos
0 links
0 symbolic links (0 fast symbolic links)
0 sockets
------------
2 files
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
grow file system to fill the partition  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
        
resize2fs -p '/dev/sdc1'  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
        
resize2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
The filesystem is already 781984 (4k) blocks long. Nothing to do!
```

Some screenshots (sorry but for some reason, I can embed the images)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnSEF.jpg

Something else that I noticed is that when(IF) showed up and click on the `62 GB Volume` it is open a new `3,2 GB Volume` directory on the file manager. Attached screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wpq3.jpg

Comment: From your question "I can delete it, and create a new one," What does this mean? Does it have something to do with the contents of the drive? Please clarify. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I mean in the GParted I can delete the partition and/or format it then create new one a with the whole space. The Ubuntu version is 22.04.1 LTS